# Denoting static variables in Ecore diagrams

Tags: java, static, emf, eclipse-emf-ecore, ecore

I'm trying to develop an ecore diagram from which code will be generated. I know that I want a particular variable to be static in the generated code so how do i denote that said variable needs to be static, in the ecore diagram?

Comment: `static` - just as singleton - considered evil in OOP. Maybe it is the cause.

Answer (score 0):

One thing you can do is directly adding after the generated code.

Comment: but how do I get that change reflected back in the ecore diagram?

Comment: I am not sure but i don't think Ecore support static properties